# Is there any way to get input variables information for a flow in managed package?

Tags: api, managed-package, visual-workflow, metadata-api, tooling-api

I use Salesforce API to check Flow's input variables information. In my org I install a managed package which have 2 Flows, each of them has one input variables.

I can get these Flows Metadata info by use Tooling API, but the variables in these Flow always show empty array.
For unmanaged flow this Tooling API works corrected. I can get flow input variable information.

May I ask is there any way to get input variables information for a flow in managed package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope none managed packages are protected packages, abstracted in nature, one is not supposed to find out any implementation details it is designed so ...maybe you ask for support from the manage package owner, if an app exchange product I am sure some kind of help mail will be there

Comment: Thank you for share your information.